# Why does input keep appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have this code and what it does is that it appends whatever the user puts in the input to the chatbox. It does the job but it also appends empty values afterward. How do I stop this?

```
function updateChat() {
  $("div#chatmessages").append("<div>" + $("#message").val() + "</div>");
}


  var elem = $('#message');

  // Save current value of element
  elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

  // Look for changes in the value
  elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
     // If value has changed...
     if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
      // Updated stored value
      elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
      $("#userSubmitTxt").click(function(){

        console.log($('#message').val());
        $("#chatmessages").append("<div>Me:" + $('#message').val() + "</div>");
        $("#chatmessages").scrollTop($("#chatmessages")[0].scrollHeight);
        if(elem.val().search(/nothing/i) >= 0){
            console.log("Nothing");
            $("#chatmessages").append("<div>Linodo: Well, for starters, have you thought about the SAT?</div>");
        }
        $('#message').val("");

      });
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: `$("#userSubmitTxt").click(...)` binds *additional* click handlers to that element every time the user types, and then each click runs *all* the handlers.

Comment: I used the `.one("click", function(){})` but it still happens

Comment: Don't nest the event handlers. Bind the `.click()` (don't use `.one()`) *outside* the keyup handler.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your listener listens for every change. Including when you set the message to ""

In your if clause please add

```
if( elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val() || $('#message').val() != "")
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to put || instead of &&